# How to fill gaps between two rows having the difference expressed in days

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe where `diff_days` is the difference between one row and the previous row

```
+----------+--------+---------+
|   fx_date|  col_1 |diff_days|
+----------+--------+---------+
|2020-01-05|       A|     null|
|2020-01-09|       B|        4|
|2020-01-11|       C|        2|
+----------+--------+---------+
```

I want to get a dataframe adding rows with missing dates and replicated values of `col_1` related to the first row.
It should be:

```
+----------+--------+
|   fx_date|  col_1 |
+----------+--------+
|2020-01-05|       A|
|2020-01-06|       A|
|2020-01-07|       A|
|2020-01-08|       A|
|2020-01-09|       B|
|2020-01-10|       B|
|2021-01-11|       C|
+----------+--------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lag` + `sequence` functions to generate the dates between previous and current row dates, then `explode` the list like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "previous_dt",
    F.date_add(F.lag("fx_date", 1).over(Window.orderBy("fx_date")), 1)
).withColumn(
    "fx_date",
    F.expr("sequence(coalesce(previous_dt, fx_date), fx_date, interval 1 day)")
).withColumn(
    "fx_date",
    F.explode("fx_date")
).drop("previous_dt", "diff_days")

df1.show()
#+----------+-----+
#|   fx_date|col_1|
#+----------+-----+
#|2020-01-05|    A|
#|2020-01-06|    B|
#|2020-01-07|    B|
#|2020-01-08|    B|
#|2020-01-09|    B|
#|2020-01-10|    C|
#|2020-01-11|    C|
#+----------+-----+
```